# Lex: multiple files, different rules

Tags: c, lex

I have to parse more than one file, with different rules for each case. That is: I need some rules to work when processing a file, and be disabled afterwards.

I could simple use a global variable to track the state of the program, and have my rules decide inside their body whether to do anything useful or not, like this:

```
%{
    static int state;
%}

%%
{something} {
    if (state == SOMETHING_STATE) ...
}

{something_else} {
    if (state == SOMETHING_ELSE_STATE) ...
}
%%
```

I'm guessing there's a better way to do this, though. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want start states -- basically lex has a builtin `state` variable and you can annotate rules as only firing in certain states

```
%s state1
%s state2
%s state3

%%

<state1>{something}    { // this rule matches only in state1
                         // change to state2
                         BEGIN(state2); }

<state1,state3>{something_else}   { // this rule matches in state1 or state 3 }

{more_stuff}        { // this rule matches in all states }
```

You can find documentation on this in any lex or flex book, or in the [online flex documentation](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using something like Flex rather than the original lex, you can use `start states`. When you parse something that changes how you do the parsing, you enter a state to do that parsing, and you tag the appropriate rules with that state. When you parse whatever marks the end of that state, you go do another:

```
{state_signal} { BEGIN(STATE2); }

<STATE2>{something} { handle_something(); }

<STATE2>{state3_signal} { BEGIN(STATE3); }

<STATE3>{something} {handle_something2(); }
<STATE3>{whatever} { BEGIN(START); }
```

Comment: The original lex has start states.  Flex adds some additional features like exclusive states.

Answer (score 0):

Using Flex and Yacc you can also build diferent individual parsers and tweak the makefile in order to compile them into a single executable. I believe you're only using Flex, but this should be possible too.

I can't precise exactly how to do it now, but i've already actually done it,quite some time ago, so if you look around you'll find a way. Basiccly you'll have to compile each parser with a diferent prefix (-P), and that will generate diferently named parse functions and diferently named global variables for the parsers to use.